# Setting pipe to read from a file c

Tags: c, pipe

Does anyone know how can I set the read (id == 1) end of the pipe to read from an open file for example fp1?

```
fp1 =fopen(argv[1],"r");
...
int id = fork();
if (id !=0){
// and this is where I stuck
}
```

Comment: you can find a good example [here](http://www.cs.loyola.edu/~jglenn/702/S2005/Examples/dup2.html)

Comment: If `fork` returns 1, your system is hosed and the appropriate reaction to that would be sheer panic. That's probably not what you meant and you should study more examples on how to use it.

Comment: the result of `fork()`  IS child process id, or 0.  It will never be 1.  Don't conflate file descriptors such as stdin (which is 0, not one) with process IDs

Comment: Yeah to speak the truth is kinda a new consept for me the pipes and forks I just wanted to ask how to read (in the read and of the pipe) the txt from an already opend file